# How to measure cpu time and wall clock time?

Tags: c, performance, time, cpu

I saw many topics about this, even on stackoverflow, for example:

[How can I measure CPU time and wall clock time on both Linux/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows)

I want to measure both cpu and wall time. Although person who answered a question in topic I posted recommend using `gettimeofday` to measure a wall time, I read that its better to use instead `clock_gettime`. So, I wrote the code below (is it ok, is it really measure a wall time, not cpu time? Im asking, cause I found a webpage: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/03/c_c_tip_how_measure_cpu_time_benchmarking#clockgettme where it says that `clock_gettime` measures a cpu time...) Whats the truth and which one should I use to measure a wall time?

Another question is about cpu time. I found the answer that `clock` is great about it, so I wrote a sample code for it too. But its not what I really want, for my code it shows me a 0 secods of cpu time. Is it possible to measure cpu time more precisely (in seconds)? Thanks for any help (for now on, Im interested only in Linux solutions).

Heres my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    double sum;

    // measure elapsed wall time
    struct timespec now, tmstart;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tmstart);
    for(i=0; i<1024; i++){
        sum += log((double)i);
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    double seconds = (double)((now.tv_sec+now.tv_nsec*1e-9) - (double)(tmstart.tv_sec+tmstart.tv_nsec*1e-9));
    printf("wall time %fs\n", seconds);

    // measure cpu time
    double start = (double)clock() /(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(i=0; i<1024; i++){
        sum += log((double)i);
    }
    double end = (double)clock() / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("cpu time %fs\n", end - start);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it like this:

> gcc test.c -o test -lrt -lm

and it shows me:

```
wall time 0.000424s
cpu time 0.000000s
```

I know I can make more iterations but thats not the point here ;)

**IMPORTANT:**

```
printf("CLOCKS_PER_SEC is %ld\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

shows

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000000
```

Comment: @sashkello: I wish I could but I need to do it myself :)

Comment: Perhaps if you were not dividing the result of the `clock()` function by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` your resolution would be better than one second, hrm?

Comment: @mah: will it give me a correct cpu time then, for sure? Here it says, that I need to divide it: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_17.html

Comment: @BrianBrown what happens when you take a number and divide it by another, does it get more accurate or less? Easier question: does it get larger or smaller? Yes, the website you link does the division in its example, but it falls on _you_ to understand the reasoning, and without doubt, whatever reason it has is not for improved resolution. As to "correct cpu time for sure" -- if clock() is returning correct cpu time, then by not modifying it, of course. NEVER type in code you find in a random place without pondering what it actually does first.

Comment: @mah: ok, you are right, I dont get it really. Why they divide it when as you say, `clock() is returning correct cpu time`? And in every example I saw on a web, there is a given division. Btw when I removed divsion, I got zeros as well

Comment: @mah: Huh ok, I see. I also read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/ there is an example, that when you need seconds, you should divide it. OMG I dont know what is right anymore

Comment: "Whats the truth and which one should I use to measure a wall time?" - The fact is that there are *many* different ways to measure wall time. Some more precise than others. Some more portable than others. You get to take you pick and use whatever suits your fancy. My answer on the question you linked uses `gettimeofday()` because that was the first thing that worked well enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my manual page on `clock` it says

> POSIX  requires  that CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 independent of the actual resolution.

When increasing the number iterations on my computer the measured cpu-time starts showing on 100000 iterations. From the returned figures it seems the resolution is actually 10 millisecond.

Beware that when you optimize your code, the whole loop may disappear because `sum` is a dead value. There is also nothing to stop the compiler from moving the `clock` statements across the loop as there are no real dependences with the code in between.

Let me elaborate a bit more on micro measurements of performance of code. The naive and tempting way to measure performance is indeed by adding `clock` statements as you have done. However since time is not a concept or side effect in C, compilers can often move these `clock` calls at will. To remedy this it is tempting to make such `clock` calls have side effects by for example having it access `volatile` variables. However this still doesn't prohibit the compiler from moving highly side-effect free code over the calls. Think for example of accessing regular local variables. But worse, by making the `clock` calls look very scary to the compiler, you will actually negatively impact any optimizations. As a result, mere measuring of the performance impacts that performance in a negative and undesirable way.

If you use profiling, as already mentioned by someone, you can get a pretty good assessment of the performance of even optimized code, although the overall time of course is increased.

Another good way to measure performance is just asking the compiler to report the number of cycles some code will take. For a lot of architectures the compiler has a very accurate estimate of this. However most notably for a Pentium architecture it doesn't because the hardware does a lot of scheduling that is hard to predict.

Although it is not standing practice I think compilers should support a `pragma` that marks a function to be measured. The compiler then can include high precision non-intrusive measuring points in the prologue and epilogue of a function and prohibit any inlining of the function. Depending on the architecture it can choose a high precision clock to measure time, preferably with support from the OS to only measure time of the current process.

Comment: according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/ I need to divide `clocks` difference by CLOCKS_PER_SEC, right? But your point is, only with 100000 or more iterations I can see results in seconds?

Comment: My point is that even though `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000000, the `clock` function will return multiples of 10000 on my system and I guess on most Linux systems. So to get a reasonable measurement you need to run the application for at least some tenths of seconds. But really my point is that it is very hard to do such micro measurements on code, because the compiler is unaware of the things you want to measure and can schedule your measuring points in unexpected ways.

Comment: @BrianBrown I've added some more elaboration on micro measurements.