# Unable to optimize using SSE

Tags: c, sse

I am testing out SSE on a variant of Zip Decryption. However, the unoptimized code is performing better.

Running the compiler with the parameters: *-msse4 -O3* results in the following benchmarks:-

Normal Test: 0.275, SSE Test: 0.655

I tried increasing the loop counter, but the benchmarks did not change much. What optimizations are being done by the compiler? Should we not be able to match it using SSE?

**Edit:** Used wall time as suggested by Jens, increased loop iterations and fixed printf format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <time.h>

//  Windows
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
double get_wall_time()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER time,freq;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq))
    {
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }
    if (!QueryPerformanceCounter(&time))
    {
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }

    return (double)time.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart;
}

double get_cpu_time()
{
    FILETIME a,b,c,d;
    if (GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(),&a,&b,&c,&d) != 0)
    {
        //  Returns total user time.
        //  Can be tweaked to include kernel times as well.
        return
            (double)(d.dwLowDateTime |
            ((unsigned long long)d.dwHighDateTime << 32)) * 0.0000001;
    }
    else
    {
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }
}

//  Posix/Linux
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
double get_wall_time()
{
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time,NULL))
    {
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }

    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * .000001;
}

double get_cpu_time()
{
    return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
#endif


static void test_sse()
{
    double start = get_wall_time();

    uint64_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t nk0 = 0x12345678;
    uint32_t nk1 = 0x23456789;
    uint32_t nk2 = 0x34567890;
    uint32_t nk3 = 0x45678901;

    __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0xff);

    uint64_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        uint32_t newKeys[] = {nk0, nk1, nk2, nk3};

        __m128i *nk_sse = (__m128i*)(&newKeys);

        __m128i opa = _mm_and_si128(*nk_sse, mask);
        __m128i opr8 = _mm_srai_epi32 (*nk_sse, 8);
        __m128i opr16 = _mm_srai_epi32 (*nk_sse, 16);
        __m128i opr24 = _mm_srai_epi32 (*nk_sse, 24);

        __m128i oprsum = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_add_epi32(_mm_add_epi32(opa, _mm_and_si128(opr8, mask)), _mm_and_si128(opr16, mask)), _mm_and_si128(opr24, mask));

        uint32_t* oprsum_ptr = (uint32_t*)(&oprsum);

        uint32_t sum_sse = oprsum_ptr[0] + oprsum_ptr[1] + oprsum_ptr[2] + oprsum_ptr[3];
        sum += sum_sse;

        nk0--;
        nk1--;
        nk2--;
        nk3--;
    }

    double end = get_wall_time();

    double ms = end - start;

    printf("SSE Test - Sum: %lu, ms: %f\n", sum, ms);
}

static void test()
{
    double start = get_wall_time();

    uint64_t sum = 0;

    uint32_t nk0 = 0x12345678;
    uint32_t nk1 = 0x23456789;
    uint32_t nk2 = 0x34567890;
    uint32_t nk3 = 0x45678901;

    uint64_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        uint8_t res0 = (uint8_t) (nk0 & 0xff);
        uint8_t res1 = (uint8_t) (nk0 >> 8);
        uint8_t res2 = (uint8_t) (nk0 >> 16);
        uint8_t res3 = (uint8_t) (nk0 >> 24);

        uint8_t res4 = (uint8_t) (nk1 & 0xff);
        uint8_t res5 = (uint8_t) (nk1 >> 8);
        uint8_t res6 = (uint8_t) (nk1 >> 16);
        uint8_t res7 = (uint8_t) (nk1 >> 24);

        uint8_t res8 = (uint8_t) (nk2 & 0xff);
        uint8_t res9 = (uint8_t) (nk2 >> 8);
        uint8_t res10 = (uint8_t) (nk2 >> 16);
        uint8_t res11 = (uint8_t) (nk2 >> 24);

        uint8_t res12 = (uint8_t) (nk3 & 0xff);
        uint8_t res13 = (uint8_t) (nk3 >> 8);
        uint8_t res14 = (uint8_t) (nk3 >> 16);
        uint8_t res15 = (uint8_t) (nk3 >> 24);

        sum += res0 + res1+ res2 + res3 + res4 + res5 + res6 + res7 + res8 + res9
        + res10 + res11 + res12 + res13 + res14  + res15;

        nk0--;
        nk1--;
        nk2--;
        nk3--;
    }

    double end = get_wall_time();

    double ms = end - start;

    printf("Normal Test - Sum: %lu, ms: %f\n", sum, ms);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    test();
    test_sse();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why compile with `-Os`?

Comment: My bad, I meant to do it with -O3. Here are the results with -O3:- Normal - 2, SSE - 6

Comment: @Partho BTW, did you read the disassembly of non-see `test`? When given -msse4, the compiler *itself* might use SSE instructions too (at least GCC promises something like that).

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong tool to measure performance. `clock`, at least on conforming platforms, gives you the CPU time and not the wall clock time.

Another thing that you are doing wrong is to print an `uint64_t` with `%d`. This has undefined behavior when `int` has less than 64 bit. Your print of the `int` for the time then might just receive garbage.

*Edit:* Now that you fixed your code, I have it compiled to assembler (gcc option `-S`). In fact gcc does an excellent job on vectorizing and unrolling your `test` function. With my three compilers that I have I get quite different results, all compiled with `-O3 -march=native`

icc:

```
Normal Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.618356
SSE Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 1.059261
```

gcc 4.6:

```
Normal Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.462793
SSE Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.348453
```

clang:

```
Normal Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.625905
SSE Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.423343
```

So icc and clang do about the same on the non-optimized code, but gcc does a much better job. with gcc and clang your sse code is better, whereas icc is a looser. In general the performance of icc, a commercial compiler for which you'd have to pay real money, is really disappointing compared to the public domain, "free" compilers.

*Edit 2:*

Now with a newer version of gcc, I even get this

gcc 4.7:

```
Normal Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.158695
SSE Test - Sum: 169248636030, ms: 0.406921
```

So you see that the "normal test" improved even much further, whereas
the SSE test is a bit worse than before.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I used wall clock time solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows). Also fixed the printf formats.