# Comparison of Sorting Algorithms using running time in terms of seconds

Tags: sorting, time, comparison, iteration

I have devised a test in order to compare the different running times of my sorting algorithm with Insertion sort, bubble sort, quick sort, selection sort, and shell sort. I have based my test using the test done in this website http://warp.povusers.org/SortComparison/index.html, but I modified my test a bit.

I set up a test manager program server which generates the data, and the test manager sends it to the clients that run the different algorithms, therefore they are sorting the same data to have no bias.

I noticed that the insertion sort, bubble sort, and selection sort algorithms really did run for a very long time (some more than 15 minutes) just to sort one given data for sizes of 100,000 and 1,000,000.
So I changed the number of runs per test case for those two data sizes. My original runs for the 100,000 was 500 but I reduced it to 15, and for 1,000,000 was 100 and I reduced it to 3.

Now my professor doubts the credibility as to why I've reduced it that much, but as I've observed the running time for sorting a specific data distribution varied only by a small percentage, which is why I still find it that even though I've reduced it to that much I'd still be able to approximate the average runtime for that specific test case of that algorithm.

My question now is, is my assumption wrong? Does the machine at times make significant running time changes (>50% changes), like say for example sorting the same data over and over if a first run would give it 0.3 milliseconds will the second run give as much difference as making it run for 1.5 seconds? Because from my observation, the running times don't vary largely given the same type of test distribution (e.g. completely random, completely sorted, completely reversed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to measure error in your experiments. My favorite book on subject is Error Analysis by Taylor and Chapter 4 has what you need which I'll summarize here.

You need to calculate *Standard error of the mean* or SDOM. First calculate mean and standard deviation (formulas are on Wikipedia and quite simple). Your SDOM is standard deviation divided by square root of number of measurements.  Assuming your timings have Normal distribution (which it should), the twice the value of SDOM  is a very common way to specify +/- error.

For example, let's say you run sorting algorithm 5 times and get following numbers: 5, 6, 7, 4, 5. Then mean is 5.4 and standard deviation is 1.1. Therefor SDOM is 1.1/sqrt(5) = 0.5. So 2*SDOM = 1. Now you can say that algorithm rum time was 5.4 ± 1. You professor can determine if this is acceptable error in measurement. Notice that as you take more readings, your SDOM, i.e. plus or minus error, goes down inversely proportional to square root of N. Twice of SDOM interval has 95% probability or confidence that the true value lies within the interval which is accepted standard.

Also you most likely want to measure performance by measuring *CPU time* instead of simple timer. Modern CPUs are too complex with various cache level and pipeline optimizations and you might end up getting less accurate measurement if you are using timer. More about CPU time is in this answer: [How can I measure CPU time and wall clock time on both Linux/Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I exactly needed!
Thanks also to the other responses, you've been of great help to me. I should have asked this here sooner.

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely does. You need a variety of "random" samples in order to be able to draw proper conclusions about the population.

Look at it this way. It takes a long time to poll 100,000 people in the U.S. about their political stance. If we reduce the sample size to 100 people in order to complete it faster, we not only reduce the precision of our final result (2 decimal places rather than 5), we also introduce a larger chance that the members of the sample have a specific bias (there is a greater chance that 100 people out of 3xx,000,000 think the same way than 100,000 out of those same 3xx,000,000).

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is right, however he's not provided the details that I mention some of them here :

1. Sampling issue: It's right that you generate some random numbers and feed them to your sorting methods, but with a few test cases indeed you're biased cause almost all of the random functions are biased to some extent (specially to the state of machine or time at the moment), so you should use more and more test cases to be more confident about the randomness.
2. Machine state: Suppose you've provide perfect data (fully representative of a uniform distribution), the performance of the electro-mechanical devises like computers may vary in different situations, so you should try for considerable times to smooth the effects of these phenomena.

**Note** : In advanced technical reports, you should provide a confidence coefficient for the answers you provide derived from statistical analysis, and proven step by step, but if you don't need to be that much exact, simply increase these :

1. The size of the data
2. The number of tests