# Measure CPU time and wall clock time of a program in C++

Tags: c++

`std::clock()` measures the number of clock ticks within the duration of your program. In the following code, does it calculate the CPU time or wall clock time?

std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

```
start = std::clock();

/* Your algorithm here */

duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

In another scenario, with the following code:

```
std::clock_t start;
double time;
start = std::clock();
time = start  / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

What will the value of time be?

Comment: This has been answered previously

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432502/how-can-i-measure-cpu-time-and-wall-clock-time-on-both-linux-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock):

> `std::clock` time may advance faster or slower than the wall clock, depending on the execution resources given to the program by the operating system.

Comment: Then, what would be a good technique to record wall clock time in C++?

Comment: @firefly Using something like `std::chrono::time_point`. (C++11)

Comment: The example at the link I shared gets wall clock time, too.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can also write a simple lambda (especially simple in C++14) that measures the time taken by any callable object, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

auto timing = [](auto&& F, auto&&... params) // need C++14 for auto lambda parameters
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    F(std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...); // execute the function 
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
               std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count();
};

void f(std::size_t numsteps) // we'll measure how long this function runs
{
    volatile std::size_t i{}; // need volatile, otherwise the compiler optimizes the loop
    for(i = 0; i < numsteps; ++i);
}

int main()
{
    auto taken = timing(f, 500'000'000); // measure the time taken to run f()
    std::cout << "Took " << taken << " milliseconds" << std::endl;

    taken = timing(f, 100'000'000); // measure again
    std::cout << "Took " << taken << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
}
```

You can then reuse the lambda whenever you want to time something.